# What is Intel's Extreme Edition CPU?

Tags: intel-core-i7

I have tried to google exactly [this question](https://www.google.ge/search?&q=what%20is%20%20Extreme%20edition), but couldn't find a simple explanation of that.

What are major differences(i.e. percentage)/pros of Extreme Edition compared to non-extreme edditions?

Comment: They are simply the most "extreme" (i.e. the best / fastest) you can get in that particular range.

Comment: [Brief: Intel® Core™ i7 Extreme Edition for the X-series Platform](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/core/core-i7-for-x-series-platform-product-brief.html)

Comment: Why the question is downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"extreme edition" parts represent the top end of Intel's desktop processor line (workstation/server parts can be considerably higher end).

They generally have the highest clock speeds and/or core count for their product line. They are also unlocked for overclocking. Since Intel split the high end and mainstream desktop parts onto different sockets, extreme edition parts have always been on the high end sockets (1366/2011/2011-3/2066) rather than the mainstream sockets (1156/1155/1150/1151).

The main downside is the price, extreme edition parts are very expensive, for many years they had a "release price" of $999. However in recent years the pricing of extreme editions has jumped up to $1723 for the i7-6950X and $1999 for the Core i9-7980XE.

Confusingly an X at the end of the part number used to indicate an extreme edition part but it now only indicates an "X-series" part, which basically seems to mean any desktop LGA2066 processor.

In many cases the gains over a much cheaper unlocked non-extreme part can be questionable. Especially if your application doesn't scale well to large numbers of cores. When buying CPUs at this level you really need to look at the actual specs and ignore the marketing names.

In recent years the high end desktop platforms have also lagged behind the mainstream desktop platforms. So while high end parts can have more cores the parts at the top of the mainstream line often have faster individual core performance.

Comment: If they have the same stepping code, the cheaper ones were made on the same wafers as the extremes, but after testing for faults had features turned off (cores, L2 cache, etc) and/or rated at lower clock speeds.